# PlotLegends in ListPlot does not display different markers

Tags: legending

I would like to plot a graph with the legends at its side. However, I have managed to plot the legends, but the markers do not match the one in plot (picture bellow):

[image: Legend is Marker shape insensitive!]

My code for that plot is:

```
ListPlot[{Table[{(n - 1/2)*1/1000, VelocityU[[1, n]]}, {n, 1, NN}], 
  Table[{(n - 1/2)*1/1000, VelocityU[[SI, n]]}, {n, 1, NN}]}, 
 Joined -> True, Filling -> None, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thin}, {Blue, Thin}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, (NN)*1/1000}, Automatic}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"y [m]", "U(y) [m/s]"}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[1/1000, 1/100, 0.001], Automatic}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> {{Dashed, Lighter[Gray], Thin}, {Dashed, 
    Lighter[Gray], Thin}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 8], 
 PlotLegends -> {"U(y, i = 1)", "U(y, i = 400)"}]
```

I have managed to solve the problem with the modified code: `PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thin}, {Red, Thin}}`, but I still cannot plot proper markers, if I want to keep the blue color for both lines.

[image: Problem partialy solved.]

And the last question, how to reduce the font size in the legend?

---

My final and working solution on my OS is the following:

```
ListPlot[{Table[{(n - 1/2)*1/1000, VelocityU[[1, n]]}, {n, 1, NN}], 
  Table[{(n - 1/2)*1/1000, VelocityU[[SI, n]]}, {n, 1, NN}]}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Filling -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thin}, {Red, Thin}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, (NN)*1/1000}, Automatic}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"y [m]", "U(y) [m/s]"}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[1/1000, 1/100, 0.001], Automatic}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> {{Dashed, Lighter[Gray], Thin}, {Dashed, 
    Lighter[Gray], Thin}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 8], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend[{"U(y, i = 1)", Row[{"U(y, i = ", ToString[SI], ")"}]}, 
   LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, Automatic}, LabelStyle -> 8]]
```

Final plot:
[image: Final solution of the problem in my case.]

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: Mathematica v10.0.1.0

Comment: It's fixed on 10.0.2 and later, so I'd recommend an upgrade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the option `LineLegend` with sub-option `LegendMarkers` as the setting for `PlotLegends`:

```
NN = 15;
data = {Table[{(n - 1/2)*1/1000, 0}, {n, 1, NN}], 
   Transpose@{Table[(n - 1/2)*1/1000, {n, 1, NN}], -Sort[-RandomInteger[10, NN]]}};

ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thin}, {Blue, Thin}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, (NN)*1/1000}, Automatic}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"U(y, i = 1)", "U(y, i = 400)"}, 
                  LegendMarkers -> Automatic]]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you maybe know how to reduce the font size of the legend?

Comment: @Mike, try the option `LabelStyle`, for example: `LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"label1", "label2", "label3"},  LabelStyle -> 10]`, or `LabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Italic, 20]`...

Comment: Your answer does not work in my case. Markers in the legend remain the same. I use Mathematica 10.0.1.0. But it works with PlotLegends -> 
 LineLegend[{"U(y, i = 1)", "U(y, i = 400)"}, 
  LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, Automatic}]

Comment: @Mike, it could be os differences: the code posted above works both in Version 9.0.1.0 (Windows 8 64-bit) and version 10 (wolfram programming cloud). `LegendMarkers -> {Automatic,Automatic}` also works in both versions.

Comment: Do you maybe know, how can I write a code with grey background in the comments? I have tried <code> </code> and 'code', but nos success.

Comment: !Mike put the code inside a pair of single quotes ( remove spaces around _code_ in  ` code `  to get  `code`)